# Voltar aos anos 90 não esta funcionando em algumas páginas do site principal

Tags: suporte

Hoje, *primeiro de abril*, o *stackoverflow* liberou uma versão *"troll"* com *layout* dos anos 90, onde se o usuário quiser pode voltar ao "normal".

Voltei!

Mas agora quero (re)**voltar pra versão comemorativa**, como faz?

Notem que na home do site principal, páginas de perfil, página de edição, etc não funcionam e nem o botão do relógio aparece:

> [image: bug na home]

Somente a página de perguntas esta funcionando normalmente:

> [image: sub-paginas]

Comment: Tem um relógio na parte de cima (próximo à pontuação/medalhas), é só clicar :-)

Comment: Ontem acho que tinha um bug que não aparecia o relógio para voltar aos 90's. Tem um cookie com name tm2019 e tm2019d, apague-os.

Comment: o relógio aparece no _meta_, mas não no _pt_.

Comment: Para mim aparece em ambos os sites, pode ser esse problema do cookie que o LINQ mencionou. O detalhe é que o relógio só aparece se vc está em uma pergunta. Se estiver na página principal, na listagem de perguntas, no seu profile ou nas filas de análise, por exemplo, o relógio não aparece.

Comment: Basta usar https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dtg2c.jpg, lembre-se, precisa ir a 88 milhas :)

Comment: elementar, meu caro @GuilhermeNascimento xD

Comment: @AdamLear por que isto seria [tag:suporte]? me parece um bug mesmo, apesar de ser algo que provavelmente não será mais usado, suporte seria quando temos duvida no uso de algo, a pergunta aqui relata um problema de funcionamento, logo isto é um bug. / Why would this be support?
seems to me a bug, although it is something that will probably no longer be used, "support" would be when we have doubts in the use of something, the question here reports a problem of functioning, so this is a "bug".

Answer (score 1):

Apague os cookies tm2019 e tm2019d.

> **Disclaimer**: Faça isso por sua própria conta e risco :p

Comment: pior que cacei esses _cookies_ no _chrome_ e não achei.. deu ruim

Comment: Não funcionou aqui, provavelmente algo esta "preso"

Comment: Editei a pergunta do AP só para clarear o problema, a home, perfil, edição, etc não funcionam, somente a de pergunta parece ok